# Can I find out if progress updates are supported in jquery file upload?

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I know there are several transports, including an iFrame one, and some browsers don't support progress updtes.

What I want to know is if there is a way to detect which transport jquery-file-upload is using, or if upload progress is supported, before issuing the request.

Right now I just have to wait for the first progress callback and swap out my custom progress bar style at that event, and I would rather be able to have an empty progress bar to start with, if I know I will receive progress events.

```
$wrapper.fileupload({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var percent = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10) + '%';
        //
        // This is the conditional I want to move 
        // into a submit or send callback.
        //
        if( $progress_bar.hasClass('static') ) {
            $progress_bar.css('width', '0%').removeClass('static');
        }
        $progress_bar.css('width', percent);
    }
});
```

Link to plugin, http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: can you please post link to the plugin you are using?